# How to prevent dragging of empty table cells with jQuery UI's draggable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

How to prevent or stop dragging empty td cells,
I'm using jQuery UI's [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/).

My code:

```
$("#demo table tr td").draggable({
         helper: 'clone',
         revert: 'invalid',
         cursor: "move",
         start: function (event, ui) {
             setValues($(this).attr('id'),$(this).val());

         },

         stop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).css('opacity', '1');

         }
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#demo table tr td:not(:empty)").draggable({
         helper: 'clone',
         revert: 'invalid',
         cursor: "move",
         start: function (event, ui) {
             setValues($(this).attr('id'),$(this).val());

         },

         stop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).css('opacity', '1');

         }
     });
```